# Android App Invite custom image size restrictions

Tags: google-app-invites

What are the size limitations for custom images for the [App Invite API](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/appinvite/AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder.html#setCustomImage(android.net.Uri))? They don't appear to be documented.

I am convinced (by trial and error) there is a size limit enforced by the API. It does not throw an exception. The invite activity simply does not display the image preview (which I find reasonable).

Some general recommendations on what size/orientation will look good with the default email would be helpful. I know there is a custom HTML option, but I'm interested in using the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: If you specify a custom image, use a square image that's around 600x600 pixels and no larger than 4000x4000 pixels.

https://developers.google.com/app-invites/android/guides/app#add-config